# Extensions of number fields

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

Let $L|K$ be an extension of number fields and consider the corresponding (integral) extension of ring of integers: $R_L|R_K$. Note that $R_L$ and $R_K$ are finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$, hence they are free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Then if $Q\subset R_L$ is a nonzero prime ideal, and we set $P:=Q\cap R_K$, then $R_L|Q$ is a finite field (**being a quotient of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$ if $R_L\cong\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $p\mathbb{Z}:=Q\cap\mathbb{Z}$**). In particular, $(R_L|Q)|(R_K|P)$ is separable.

I can't understand the bold part, in particular when he says "a quotient of"

Comment: Finite integral domains are fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that the author means the following.

You have probably proved earlier in the course that $R_L\cong\mathbb{Z}^n$ as an abelian group. Because $p\in Q$, and $Q$ is an ideal, it then follows that
$$
pR_L\subseteq Q\subset R_L.
$$
This implies that 
$$
R_L/Q\cong (R_L/pR_L)/(Q/pR_L).
$$
But here $R/pR_L=(\mathbb{Z}^n)/p(\mathbb{Z}^n)=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n,$ so we have just written the field $R_L/Q$ (it's a domain because $Q$ is prime, and as pointed out by Billy, it's then a field) as a quotient of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$.